# How do I block CURL and WGET using Node.js

Tags: node.js

I am building a Node.js powered website. I want to block anyone trying to CURL or WGET my website, how do I do that?

Comment: which means you want users to only be able to view it with a browser?

Comment: Why would you want to block them?

Comment: It is impossible to block `cURL` or `wget` without also blocking every other client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can check the `User-Agent` header value, this is easily spoofed or it can be not sent altogether (both `curl` and `wget` can customize this header). So trying to block any particular client based on that header is unreliable.

Answer (score 1):

```
var origin = req.headers.origin;
```

use this code to get the origin of the client

The origin will be undefined if the request is from cURL

Then block the request using if condition ,if it has undefined in origin :-)